# How can i create hash table using PDAs?

Tags: anchor, pda, hashing

I want to create a hash-table using PDAs with seeds including: i) table-name  ii) a u32 integer as key

I tried this:

```
#[account(
    init,
    payer=user,
    space = 8 + 1 + 32 + 8 + 8,
    seeds = [b"users_table", a_u32_int.as_ref()],
    bump
)]
pub users_table: Account<'info, UsersTable>,
```

But here, I was not able to use u32 integer as reference.

Github-copilor suggested this `seeds = [b"users_table", 0u32.to_le_bytes().as_ref()]`, but I am not sure what `.to_le_bytes()` mean in rust

Also I don't know how I can generate a PDA-address for this in frontend to send as parameter for anchor program's accounts as `await PublicKey.findProgramAddress()` does not support numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create hashmaps and nested hashmaps this way

On contract-side:

```
#[account(mut)]
pub user: Signer<'info>,

// data for seeds from counter-account can be read from other pda-account 
// this is helpful when you want to track and store size of hash-map on-chain
#[account(
        seeds = [b"counter"],
        bump = counter.bump,
    )]
pub counter: Account<'info, CounterInfo>,


#[account(
    init,
    payer=user,
    space = 8 + 1 + 32 + 8 + 8,
    seeds = [format!("users_table-{}-{}", counter.index1, counter.index2).as_ref()],
    bump,
)]
pub users_table: Account<'info, UsersTable>,
```

---

On client side, we can get pda-address as:

```
const num1 = 3, num2 = 15
const [usersTablePDA, _] = await PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
  [
    anchor.utils.bytes.utf8.encode(`users_table-${num1}-${num2}`),
  ],
  program.programId
)
```

I am beginner at rust and solana, suggestion from a experienced developer about code safety will be helpful

Answer (score 2):

`await PublicKey.findProgramAddress()` expects a [`Buffer` or `Uint8Array`](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/PublicKey.html#findProgramAddress), and the program's address.

#### `u8`

So you could perhaps do (i have not tested it):

```
const yourIndex = a; // a u8 number ranging from 0 and 255
const pda = await PublicKey.findProgramAddress([utf8.encode('users_table'), [yourIndex]], programId)
```

This limits you to the range of a `Uint8` so that might not be good enough.

On the Rust side you'd have to store this index in another account and get it something like:

```
seeds = [b"users_table", &[other_account.your_index_u8]],
```

#### `u32`

If you like to use [`u32`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u32.html), like in your example, you could store many more indices (namely 4 bytes of memory).

In that case it would look something like

```
const yourIndex = new BN(a);
const byteArray = yourIndex.toArray('le', 4);
const pda = await PublicKey.findProgramAddress([utf8.encode('users_table'), byteArray], programId)
```

And on the Rust side:

```
seeds = [b"users_table", other_account.your_index_u32.to_le_bytes().as_ref()]],
```

FYI: [`.to_le_bytes()` for `u32`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u32.html#method.to_le_bytes)

> Return the memory representation of this integer as a byte array in little-endian byte order.

This means it will convert the integer into 4 x `u8` bytes, to represent it.

Comment: `const yourIndex = a; // UInt8Array of length 4`, I does not find one-line syntax to convert a number to UintArray of lengh 4 in javascript, do you know any ?

Comment: @MaheshGhamaand you should use the ``BN()`` module for that.


`const yourIndex = new BN(a);`
`const byteArray = yourIndex.toArray('le', 4);`


Note the `le` Endianness should match the order that you use on the contract side. So `to_le_bytes()` !

Have updated my answer.